# Pasaje de arreglos por referencia en un procedimiento

Tags: array

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Tengo que hacer un procedimiento con dos arreglos como parámetros, uno por valor y otro por referencia. Mi duda es que cuando compilo me da un error que dice "arr" y "arr2" **was not declared in this scope**.

Dejo este codigo mucho mas básico:

```
void Prueba(int arr[],int arr2[]) {
    if (arr[1]==3) arr2[1]=3;
        else arr2[1]=8;
}
```

La cuestión es que cuando lo dejo así el procedimiento funciona bien, pero si le pongo el "&" al lado de arr2 para indicar que es un pasaje por referencia, me tira ese error.

¿Por qué pasa esto?

Comment: Estoy utilizando un compilador de C++, el Dev C++, ¿no debería funcionar bien así?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La declaración de los parámetros de la función es correcta. Los arrays SIEMPRE son referencias ya que son punteros.

Puedes declararlo así:

`int arr[]`

o asi:

`int *arr`

pero nunca con &, eso solo es para la invocación a la función.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! En el caso de pasar una variable entera tipo "int a" como parámetro, si sería necesario poner el "&" para indicar que es por referencia, ¿no?

Comment: Correcto. En el caso de variables simples puedes pasarlas como valor o referencia. Pero los arrays son siempre referencias.